# Unir dois Select

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Estou desenvolvendo um relatório no PowerBuilder e gostaria de saber como faço para unir  resultados de duas queries SQL no relatório. 
Se eu adicionar a função  f_bloqueto_nosso_numero na primeira querie e adicionar a tabela fatura no from , os registros multiplicam no relatório por isso eu queria deixar uma querie somente para trazer o nosso numero

```
Ex : 
  Nome  Nosso Numero
  José      007
  José      007
  José      007
```

Acredito que isso ocorra por causa v_arrecadacao é uma View que contem dados da tabela Fatura.

Porem não posso fazer o select direto na tabela fatura por causa a mesma não possui todos os dados para o relatório , já a View dados de possui diversas tabelas.

```
select v_arrecadacao.tipo,
       v_arrecadacao.idregiao,
       v_arrecadacao.idbairro,
       v_arrecadacao.idrota,
       v_arrecadacao.sequencia_leit,
       v_arrecadacao.iduc,
       v_arrecadacao.idclasse,
       v_arrecadacao.refaturamento,
       v_arrecadacao.retificado,
       v_arrecadacao.numero_reaviso,
       v_arrecadacao.nome,
       v_arrecadacao.numero_fiscal,
       v_arrecadacao.ano_mes,
       v_arrecadacao.ano_mes_original,
       v_arrecadacao.tipo_calculo,
       v_arrecadacao.data,
       v_arrecadacao.datahora,

           v_arrecadacao.empresas_nome,
        v_arrecadacao.idagente,
        v_arrecadacao.agentearrecadador_nome,
        v_arrecadacao.datahora,
        v_arrecadacao.valor_recebido as valor_recebido,
        v_arrecadacao.situacao,
        v_arrecadacao.valor_diferenca,
```

f_bloqueto_nosso_numero(33,3265,fatura.tipo_calculo,fatura.idcodfatura,fatura.vcto,fatura.iduc,fatura.ano_mes,13000617) as nosso_numero,
       nvl((select uc.ligado 
              from uc
             where uc.iduc = v_arrecadacao.iduc),'S') as ligado,
       nvl((select uc.idmotivodeslig 
              from uc
             where uc.iduc = v_arrecadacao.iduc),0) as idmotivodeslig

from v_arrecadacao, fatura

where v_arrecadacao.data BETWEEN :pagto_ini AND :pagto_final
 and  v_arrecadacao.motivo_baixa = 1

UNION

select 
      fatura.iduc,
      fatura.vcto ,
      fatura.tipo_calculo,
      fatura.idcodfatura,
      fatura.ano_mes , 
     f_bloqueto_nosso_numero(33,3265,fatura.tipo_calculo,fatura.idcodfatura,fatura.vcto,fatura.iduc,fatura.ano_mes,13000617) as nosso_numero

from fatura

where fatura.iduc = v_arrecadacao.iduc

Comment: Qual a diferença entre as queries ? Um OUTER JOIN NÃO DISPENSARIA O union ? Para um UNION ser feitos o números e os tipos de colunas devem coincidir, as queries devem ser "homogêneas" , só quem conhece o negócio pode dizer que colunas se aplicam m um union.

Comment: @Motta , solucionei o problema , eu não havia inserido as chaves primarias da View e da tabela no WHERE , por isso os registros multiplicados na exibição do relatório.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para unir duas consultas, geralmente é utilizada a instrução UNION ALL. Você precisa apenas garantir que todas as queries do UNION ALL possuem a mesma quantidade de colunas.

Segue referência:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm

Abraços,

Comment: Vlw pela referencia @Dias 

Abraços.